# If the kernel of an irreducible character contains the derived subgroup - is it then linear?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, character-theory

It is of course true that any linear character of a group contains the commutator subgroup. But is the converse also true? If not - do you know of a counterexample?

Comment: If it is irreducible over an algebraically closed field